# Edge not crossing other edges in a TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
%\usepackage{tkz-graph}


\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\textwidth16cm
\begin{document}

\def\kob{circle (3pt)} % kółko białe
\def\koc{circle (3pt)} % kółko czarne do \filldraw[black]

\def\ticircw{\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}
  \SetVertexNoLabel
%\grEmptyPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=2,RS=0]{5}
%\grEmptyPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=2,RS=3]{5}
\grPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=0.5,RS=0]{6}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.25 cm]
\grPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=1,RS=1.73]{1}
\grPath[Math,prefix=n,RA=1,RS=-1.73]{1}
%\EdgeFromOneToAll{r}{q}{0}{4}
\Edges(q0,p0,n0,p1,q0,p2,n0,p3,q0,p4,n0,p5,q0);
\Edge[style={bend right=120}](p0)(p5)
\draw[fill=white] (p0)\kob;
\filldraw[black] (p1)\koc;
\draw[fill=white] (p2)\kob;
\filldraw[black] (p3)\koc;
\draw[fill=white] (p4)\kob;
\filldraw[black] (p5)\koc;
\filldraw[black] (q0)\koc;
\draw[fill=white](n0)\kob;

%\draw[fill=white] (p2)\kob;
%\draw[fill=white] (q3)\kob;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives 
[image]

(the black part).

Is there any standard possibility to change the black curve to a curve not crossing edges, as the red one?

Comment: Try adding `\node (proforma) [inner sep=0pt,below= 1cm of n0] {}; \path [draw,bend left=77] (proforma) to (p0); \path [draw,bend right=77] (proforma) to (p5);` at the end of your tikzpicutre right before `\end{scope}`. Not yet finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I missed the fact that these were coordinates, not nodes, and used the parameters from Przemysław Scherwentke's comment, and made the code a bit leaner (thanks to @cfr).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\textwidth16cm
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}
\def\kob{circle (3pt)}
\def\koc{circle (3pt)}
  \SetVertexNoLabel
\grPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=0.5,RS=0]{6}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.25 cm]
\grPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=1,RS=1.73]{1}
\grPath[Math,prefix=n,RA=1,RS=-1.73]{1}
\Edges(q0,p0,n0,p1,q0,p2,n0,p3,q0,p4,n0,p5,q0);
\coordinate (b0) at ([yshift=-15pt]n0);
\draw[blue,thick] (p0) to [out=-105,in=180] (b0) to [out=0,in=-75] (p5);
\draw[fill=white] (p0)\kob;
\filldraw[black] (p1)\koc;
\draw[fill=white] (p2)\kob;
\filldraw[black] (p3)\koc;
\draw[fill=white] (p4)\kob;
\filldraw[black] (p5)\koc;
\filldraw[black] (q0)\koc;
\draw[fill=white](n0)\kob;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but I will wait a little for possible other solutions.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Sure. Just for curiosity: what features should the solution have? Do you want it to automatically avoid crossings? Or do you want it to use the `\Edge` syntax?

Comment: Avoiding crossing automatically seems to be very difficult. However, some possibilities of controlling distance of the rounded edge from a vertex would give me enough control on the shape of a graph.

Comment: It seems that you prepared the needed parts. After changing to `\coordinate (b0) at ([yshift=-15pt]n0);
\draw(p0) to [out=-105,in=180] (b0) to [out=0,in=-75] (p5);` it looks pretty good for me.

Comment: Adding +1 for your excellent work.

Comment: What's the point of defining `\ticircw`? @PrzemysławScherwentke ?

Comment: @cfr To remove standard circles in vertices. Is there a different method?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I guess the question is why you need to define a macro that does the `\tikzset` rather than just using `\tikzset{...`.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke You never use the macro. You define it, but nothing else. What does it do?

Comment: @cfr It is left from a much larger file. So it is only Near Minimal (non)Working Example.

Comment: @cfr As for your question: "What does it do?" : I makes the code look more professional ;-)